# Does initialized java array go onto stack or heap?

Tags: java, arrays, heap-memory, stack-memory

```
void someMethod() {
  byte[] array = { 0, 0 };
}
```

Will this array be stored in heap or on the stack?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can *think* of it as always going on the heap.

I believe some smart VMs are able to stack-allocate objects if they can detect it's safe - but conceptually it's on the heap. In particular, all array types are reference types (even if the element type is primitive), so the `array` variable (which is on the stack) is just a reference to an object, and objects normally go on the heap.

In particular, imagine a small change:

```
byte[] someMethod() { 
    byte[] array = { 0, 0 };
    return array;
}
```

If the array were allocated on the stack, what would the returned reference have to refer to?

Answer (score 2):

It will be stored in the heap